# Using Light DOM with iron-list throws Illegal Invocation error

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I've built an `<editable-list>` element that allows me to declare some items in the element's Light DOM for `dom-repeat`ing them.

For performance reasons, I'd like to use an `<iron-list>` instead of a `<dom-repeat>`.

While the documentation states that `<iron-list>` [does indeed have a Templatize method](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-list#method-templatize), I seem to get a:

> Illegal Invocation

error when I attempt to templatize the Light DOM into the `<iron-list>`.

#### Non-working code sample (uses `<iron-list>`):

```html
<base href="https://polygit.org/components/">
<script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
<link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">
<link href="iron-list/iron-list.html" rel="import">

<dom-module id="editable-list">
  <template>
    <content></content>
    <iron-list id="repeater" items="{{data}}"></iron-list>
  </template>
  <script>
    HTMLImports.whenReady(function() {
      "use strict";

      Polymer({

        is: "editable-list",
        
        ready: function() {
          const template = this.querySelector("#items");
          this.$.repeater.templatize(template);
          Polymer.Bind.prepareModel(this.$.repeater);
          Polymer.Base.prepareModelNotifyPath(this.$.repeater);
        }

      });
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>


<dom-module id="user-list">
  <template>
    <editable-list data="{{data}}">
      <template id="items">
        <h4>[[item]]</h4>
      </template>
    </editable-list>
  </template>
  <script>
    HTMLImports.whenReady(function() {
      "use strict";

      Polymer({

        is: "user-list",
        properties: {
         data: {
           type: Array,
           value: ["Foo", "Bar", "Baz"]
         }
        }

      });
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>


<user-list></user-list>
```

#### Working code sample (uses `dom-repeat`)

```html
<base href="https://polygit.org/components/">
<script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
<link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">

<dom-module id="editable-list">
  <template>
    <content></content>
    <template is="dom-repeat" id="repeater" items="{{data}}"></template>
  </template>
  <script>
    HTMLImports.whenReady(function() {
      "use strict";

      Polymer({

        is: "editable-list",
        
        ready: function() {
          const template = this.querySelector("#items");
          this.$.repeater.templatize(template);
          Polymer.Bind.prepareModel(this.$.repeater);
          Polymer.Base.prepareModelNotifyPath(this.$.repeater);
        }

      });
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>


<dom-module id="user-list">
  <template>
    <editable-list data="{{data}}">
      <template id="items">
        <h4>[[item]]</h4>
      </template>
    </editable-list>
  </template>
  <script>
    HTMLImports.whenReady(function() {
      "use strict";

      Polymer({

        is: "user-list",
        properties: {
         data: {
           type: Array,
           value: ["Foo", "Bar", "Baz"]
         }
        }

      });
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>


<user-list></user-list>
```

Comment: why don't you manipulate just the `<iron-list>` items array? you don't need to override the whole template system for this job. You should make the editable-item as the item and put inside the iron list template which can give the item data to your item.

Comment: @Adamos42 Sorry  - just now figured out what you meant. Use the Light DOM to wrap the contents of an item (excluding the list), and then wrap that item in an `iron-list`. Makes sense but theres other reasons why I'd like to avoid that and encapsulate the whole list instead. This shouldn't really fail so spectacularly since the `Templatizer` is meant to be used for this job

Comment: I have to test out my approach, interesting to see a dom-template solution for this kind of job. I try to get the `<template>` from the slot and put inside the `<iron-list>` so the list will have it's template for working :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Propagating Light DOMs are not supported in `<iron-list>` for the time being, at least for v1.

The Issue is being tracked [here](https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-list/issues/356).